# onBindViewHolder must be declared abstract

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, picasso

I am getting the error : class "FlickrRecyclerViewAdapter" must either be declared abstract or implement method abstract method onBindViewHolder(VH, int) in 'Adapter'

While this error should be self explanitory, I have implemended onBindViewHolder and the error is still present.

Relvant Code -

```
public class FlickrRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private List<Photo> mPhotosList;
    private Context mContext;

    public FlickrRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Photo> photosList) {
        mContext = context;
        this.mPhotosList = photosList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FlickrImageViewHolder flickrImageViewHolder, int i) {

            Photo photoItem = mPhotosList.get(i);
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(photoItem.getmImage())
                    .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .into(flickrImageViewHolder.thumbnail);

        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of The adapter is

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<VH extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

where `VH` is the a subclass of `ViewHolder`. So you can either change the signature of you onBindViewHolder like

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder flickrImageViewHolder, int i) {
```

or change

```
extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
```

with

```
extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FlickrImageViewHolder> {
```

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView.Adapter` that you have extended has a method :

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
```

that you have to override. With the method signature that your are using you have to extend like this :

```
public class FlickrRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FlickrImageViewHolder>
```